# Strange comportment of stepper motor while connected to internet

Tags: arduino-uno

Problem moving a stepper motor after reading a value from a webpage....

I have a project to move a stepper motor from an angle after reading a number from internet; I have a typical 28BYJ-48 stepper with the hardware driver and an arduino + ethernet shield.

I have tested the motor alone with different library and it is working very well, the motor turn correctly to the proper angle and without shaking.

I have also been able to read a specific page with a number on it with the Ethernet shield and library. I am able to light a led whenever a certain value is read from this webpage.

Once I connect the 2 parts, either the stepper motot is vibrating a lot and moving from half the correct angle, either it is only shaking and not moving at all....

Note: I have powered it with an external power source thinking it was because of power issues but it doesn't change anything.....

I don't get it... Why would it work well before the etheret connection an not after?? Maybe it's late and I miss something obvious, but frankly I spent a lot of time looking online and checking my code

Here is my sketch if it anyone could help... thanks a lot in advance, I know it's quite long....but i'm quite desperate :-(

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//CONFIGURE
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define HALFSTEP 8

// Motor pin definitions
#define motorPin1  8     // IN1 on the ULN2003 driver 1
#define motorPin2  9     // IN2 on the ULN2003 driver 1
#define motorPin3  10     // IN3 on the ULN2003 driver 1
#define motorPin4  11    // IN4 on the ULN2003 driver 1

// Initialize with pin sequence IN1-IN3-IN2-IN4 for using the AccelStepper with 28BYJ-48
AccelStepper stepper1(HALFSTEP, motorPin1, motorPin3, motorPin2, motorPin4);
const int stepsPerRev =  2038;


byte server[] = { 192,168,0,11 }; //ip Address of the server you will connect to
String serverIP = "192.168.0.11";

int port = 8888; // server port

// if need to change the MAC address (Very Rare)
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
// byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 0, 188 }; // case we want to use fixed IP


//The location to go to on the server
//make sure to keep HTTP/1.0 at the end, this is telling it what type of file it is
String webPage = "/index.php HTTP/1.0";

EthernetClient client;

char inString[32]; // string for incoming serial data
int stringPos = 0; // string index counter
boolean startRead = false; // is reading?
int ledPin = 5;
String pageValue;


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SETUP
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// setup the stepper parameters

void setup() {
  stepper1.setMaxSpeed(3000.0);
  stepper1.setAcceleration(1000.0);
  stepper1.setSpeed(500);


// start a full rotation ==> this is perfectly working!!

int steps = degreesToSteps(360);
  stepper1.moveTo(steps);
  stepper1.runToPosition();


   Serial.begin(9600);

   Serial.println("starting communication");

  //Connect the Ethernet Shield by specifying the board's mac and ip address

  if(Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
   }else{
    Serial.println("Ethernet shield connected & obtained IP address : ");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());


   //Shield already connected during setup phase, now connect to the webpage and retrieve the value

    //Connect to the server
    if(!connectToServer(server, port, webPage)){
        Serial.println("Failed to connect to server");

        }else{

               Serial.println("connected to server page");

               //Read the output value written on the webpage

              int angle = readPage().toInt();
              Serial.println(angle); 

              int steps = degreesToSteps(angle);
              Serial.println(steps);

              stepper1.moveTo(steps);       

              stepper1.runToPosition();

              delay(1000);

      //end of success case connection  
      } 



   }

 //end of setup
 }





void loop(){}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Connect to a web page 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


boolean connectToServer(byte* server, int port, String webPage)
{
  //connect to the server
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  //port 8888 for our mamp server
  if (client.connect(server, port)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.print("GET ");
    client.println(webPage);
    client.println();
    return true;
  }else{
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return false;
  }

}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Parse a value located between a < and a >
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



String readPage(){
  //read the page, and capture & return everything between '<' and '>'

  stringPos = 0;
  memset( &inString, 0, 32 ); //clear inString memory

  while(true){

    if (client.available()) {
      char c = client.read();

      if (c == '<' ) { //'<' is our begining character
        startRead = true; //Ready to start reading the part 
      }else if(startRead){

        if(c != '>'){ //'>' is our ending character
          inString[stringPos] = c;
          stringPos ++;
        }else{
          //got what we need here! We can disconnect now

          startRead = false;
          client.stop();
          client.flush();
          Serial.println("disconnecting.");
          return inString;

        }

      }
    }

  }

}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Convert the degrees into the closest number of steps relative to the step motor model.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int degreesToSteps(float angleDegrees) {
  //return the closest number of steps to accomplish to move the motor for the specified angle

  const float stepsPerDegree = stepsPerRev/360.00;
  int steps = angleDegrees * stepsPerDegree + 0.5;  // we add 0.5 as when converting to an int the floating part is truncated, this allows to round the value to the nearest Int
  return steps;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pin 11 is used for SPI to communicate with the Ethernet Shield. And pin 10 is used for the ChipSelect.
 So using the ethernet shield will toggle those pins, making the motor shake around.

Try using pins 6, 7, 8, and 9 instead.

Comment: Top!!!  It worked perfectly!! Thanks a lot you helped me a lot!!! Now I will have this interferences in mind and check each shield for each pin configuration inside the libraries!